# React Native: react-native-router-flux type Property issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am using react-native-router-flux react native library for navigation but **type** Property not working

```
<Route name="error" component={Error} title="Error"  type="reset"/>
```

it give error like

```
_this2[type] is not a function.
```

react-native-router-flux version 4.0.0-beta.28

Comment: Does it work if you set type="push"?

Comment: No it is also not working

Answer (score 1):

The thing is type should use in `<Scene>` not in `<Route>`

here the working example

```
import { Router, Scene, Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
<Router>
      <Scene key="root">
        <Scene key="login" component={LoginForm} hideNavBar={'true'} initial={true} />
        <Scene key="signin" component={SigninForm} />
        <Scene
          type="reset"
          key="dashboard"
          component={NavigationView}
          initial={props.isLogin}
          hideNavBar={'true'}
        />
      </Scene>
    </Router>
```

well there is other way:
remove type from scene and use it as a param when moving to other screen.

```
Actions.error({ type:'reset' });
or
Actions.reset('KEY'); // this one is work, i just tested now.
```

or you can `replace` see this
https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/467

Comment: I tried this, but it is not working, it gives same error.

Comment: @Priya mention your library version. and add complete code like i did. it will help to understand flow

Answer (score 0):

you can pass js files as

```
<Router hideNavBar={true}>
            <Stack key="root" hideNavBar={true}>
                <Scene key="splashscreen" component={SplashScreen} title="SplashScreen" initial={true}></Scene>

            </Stack>
        </Router>
```

and whichever page you want to go you can pass 
`Actions.splashscreen()`
(need to pass key written in scene)